# How do I print out one factorial number? My code keeps printing out too many numbers and I do not know why?

Tags: python

#Python Printing out Factorial number

#Input ask for a number

```py
iMax = int(input("What is the number to factorialize: "))

iFactorial = 1
iCount = 1
```

## While loop

```py
while iCount <= iMax:
    iFactorial = iFactorial * iCount
    iCount = iCount + 1
```

## Print Factorial

```py
print("factorial of ", iMax, " is ", iFactorial)
```

Comment: it prints only 1 answer

Comment: @cmgchess The code seems correct, it may have some indentation error.

Comment: This is what I get What is the number to factorialize: 4
factorial of  4  is  1
factorial of  4  is  2
factorial of  4  is  6
factorial of  4  is  24

Comment: I only want it to print 24 out not all the other numbers

Comment: @meg aha gotcha. your code is perfectly fine. only mistake is that you have your print statement inside the while loop thats why it prints in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a better way to compute factorial:

```
num = int(input())
fac = 1

for i in range(1, num + 1):
  fac *= i

print("The factorial of", num, "is", fac)
```